# opengl :how to compute transformation matrix?

Tags: opengl, geometry, linear-algebra

I need to compute the opengl transformation matrix that transforms a rectangle A,B,C,D into the polygon A',B,C,D (that differs from the first one for 1 point).
How can i do that?

Comment: That's generally not a linear transformation, so I don't think it can be expressed as a transformation matrix.

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes and no transform matrices can reoresent also non linear transforms but not all so until a degree it could be possible like dari is proposing in answer of his

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to formalize the problem. You have a matrix M and 4 points that get transformed to another 4 points.

```
M*A = A'
M*B = B
M*C = C
M*D = D
```

Every line can be written as 4 equations. For example:

```
M11*A1 + M12*A2 + M13*A3 + M14*A4 = A'1
M21*A1 + M22*A2 + M23*A3 + M24*A4 = A'2
...
```

As a result you get 16 linear equations that can be solved with the Guassian elimination. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: just need to add: and if there is a solution for this system of equations then the matrix exist (and the coefficients are the solution) otherwise it can not be solved by transform matrix and need polynomial of higher order. and also the instead of GEM I would use jus inverse matrix

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

I implemented your solution, but unfortunately it finds a general transformation matrix, and not always an affine transofmation (which i need).

I finally solved my problem using opencv::estimateAffine3D http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#estimateaffine3d